# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type &X to an rvalue of type X

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors

I wanna modify this threadpool implementation http://roar11.com/2016/01/a-platform-independent-thread-pool-using-c14/ to remove future return. My functions does not need to return anything but I'm having trouble modifying the submit function to do that.

```
    template <class Func, class... Args>
    void submit(Func &&func, Args &&... args)
    {
        auto boundTask = std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), 
                         std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        m_workQueue.push(std::make_unique<ThreadTask<decltype(boundTask)>>(std::move(boundTask)));
    }
```

Which I use it like this

```
pool_.submit([](int i){std::cout << i << std::endl;}, 1);
```

But it give me the following error

```
./include/concurrency/ThreadPool.h: In instantiation of ‘bool 
 conc::ThreadPool::submit(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = 
 zia::ZiaServer::startService()::<lambda(int)>; Args = {int}]’:
 src/ZiaServer.cpp:16:65:   required from here
 ./include/concurrency/ThreadPool.h:85:9: error: cannot bind non-const 
 lvalue reference of type ‘std::unique_ptr<conc::IThreadTask>&’ to an 
 rvalue of type ‘std::unique_ptr<conc::IThreadTask>’
     tasks_.push(std::make_unique<ThreadTask<decltype(boundTask)>>
 (std::move(boundTask)));
```

Any idea of what's going on ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. What's `SQueue`? What's the signature of its `push` member? Etc.

Comment: I added the source source ;)

Comment: The code behind the link does not correspond to the error. Can you isolate a *minimal* reproducer and post that directly in the question?